# What is wrong in this Haskell function?

Tags: haskell

I decided to dive in functional programming world recently, and a friend told me about Haskell. I started my own researches on the language particularity and soon I got the main concepts. Then, I started working with lists and decided to rewrite some existent functions, just to practice.

I made my version of the `reverse` function, and called it `revert`. The function is defined as below:

```
revert :: [a] -> [a]
revert [] = []
revert a = revert (tail a) ++ [head a]
```

It works perfectly for me, as you can see in the image:

[image: works]

But then, I decided to make another test, receiving the result of the `revert` function on the same variable that I passed as a parameter, as you can see below:

[image]

It seems to execute the function normally, but when I check the value of `x`, it looks like it goes into a loop, and I need to interrupt the operation.

If I set the value on another variable, it works perfectly:

```
let y = revert x
```

Why does it happen? Is it some concept of functional programming that I am missing? Or some peculiarity with Haskell? I did some googling but was not able to get to an answer

PS: Sorry for the bad english

Comment: If you use the built-in function, what does `let x = reverse x` do?

Comment: It's _sort of_ a pecularity with haskell. It has nothing do with your function, the problem is that newly declared names are visible in their own definition, so `let x = revert x` means that `x = revert (revert (revert (revert (revert ...)))))` and so on.

Comment: @JoshLee, it has the same result

Comment: please don't paste images of text

Comment: also you can try `let x = x`, canonical case.

Comment: @karakfa I think I understood, thank you

Comment: This is indeed a peculiarity of Haskell. In Haskell, every binding is recursive. Instead, functional languages in the ML family have both `let` (non recursive) and `let rec`. In ML, `let x=5 in let x=x+1 in 10+x` evaluates to `10+(5+1)` since `x=x+1` actually means `inner_x = outer_x+1` rather than a recursive definition. Anyway, it's not a big deal once you know how each language works.

Comment: If you want to shadow the name in `do` notation or GHCi, you can use `x <- pure (revert x)`; this desugars to `pure (revert x) >>= \x -> …`, so unlike in a `let` binding, they’re not the same `x`.

Comment: For what it's worth, your english is excellent.

Comment: @luqui Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're defining

```
x = revert x
```

So, substituting on the right, this gives

```
x = revert (revert x)
```

And so on. Another example would be

```
a = a + 1
```

To find out what `a` is, we need to evaluate the right hand side of the definition.

```
a = (a + 1) + 1
a = ((a+1)+1) + 1
```

And so on.

Bootom line: Haskell's `=` is very different from `=` in languages like C#, where it means *assignment*. In Haskell it means *is defined as* and this means we can substitute any occurance of an identifier with its definition without changing the meaning of the program. This is called *referential transpareny*.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I think I could not figure it out before becaus this works on languages like C#. But it all makes sense now, thanks